# PolymerJS: How to output Model data?

Tags: javascript, polymer, vue.js

Is there a way to output all model data of polymer elements?

I would like to output each property and their value to the view.

I know vue accomplishes this, by using

```
{{ $data | json }}
```

But **Vue** also has a data attribute that is *dumpable*. Not sure if it is even possible in polymer to dump every property and their value into the view.

I'd like to use something similar with polymer. But how?

I know doing something like this doesn't work:

```
{{ $properties }}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no filters in data bindings in PolymerJS like vue has.

But you can use so called [Computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed):

```
<dom-module id="view">

  {{dump(model)}}

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'view',
      properties: {
        model: Object       
      },
      dump: function(model) {
        return JSON.stringify(model, null, ' ');
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```